# Как можно привязать свой Html-код к WebBrowser в WPF

Tags: wpf, webbrowser, visual-studio

У меня есть строка содержащая html-код. Как можно привязать её к контролу WebBrowser который бы отображал страницу с этим кодом?

Answer (score 1):

Метод [`NavigateToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.navigatetostring%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) вам в помощь.

**UPD**

А [вот здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585782/displaying-html-from-string-in-wpf-webbrowser-control) описан способ привязки свойства `Html` к `WebBrowser` и отслеживания его изменений с обновлением содержимого `WebBrowser`.

Comment: Это конечно здорово, но мне нужна привязка, чтобы при изменении переменной и браузер перерисовывал всё

Comment: Я находил эту статью, но не понял откуда берется lcl в <WebBrowser lcl:BrowseBehavior.Html="{Binding HtmlToDisplay}" />

Comment: И кстати что-то она не работает.

Comment: Это namespace, в котором ищется свойство `BrowseBehavior.Html`. Указывается как свойство корневого элемента xml-ки примерно так: `xmlns:lcl="clr-namespace:ИМЯ_NAMESPACE;assembly=ИМЯ_СБОРКИ"`

Comment: добавил namespace но все равно не хочет работать